# How to share data between two different components?

Tags: angular, sharedservices

i'm trying to share a list of selected items from a component to an other one.
i created a service to declare the list :

```
  public selectedTasksToUnassign = [];
```

then in this component i try to set the list values:

**component_1.ts**

```
checkTask(task) {
if (task) {
  if (this.selectedTasks.includes(task)) {
    this.selectedTasks.splice(this.selectedTasks.indexOf(task), 1);
  } else {
    this.selectedTasks.push(task);
  }
} else {
  if (this.selectedTasks.length < this.tasks.length) {
    this.selectedTasks = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this.selectedTasks, this.tasks);
  } else {
    this.selectedTasks = [];
  }
}
this.tasksToSelect.emit(this.selectedTasks);
this.formService.selectedTasksToUnassign=this.selectedTasks;
console.log("task to unassign from table", this.formService.selectedTasksToUnassign);
  }
```

and in this component i want to get the list :
**component_2.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
console.log("test tasks to unassign",this.formService.selectedTasksToUnassign);
 }
```

in fact im seeing that everytime i check an item in my table the liste is updated in the console.log in **component_1.ts** and im seeying the values are added but in the console.log in **component_2.ts** , it shows me only the first value selected !!!

Comment: I suggest you to see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q-HL9YX_pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because (I'm assuming) you're invoking `checkTask()` each time you interact with the task list. Because `checkTask()` includes the `console.log`, you're seeing it with every interaction in component_1.

However, on component_2 you have a `console.log` on the `ngOnInit()` which runs only once when the component is loaded. That's why you only see the first `console.log`.

If you bind `formService.selectedTaskToUnassign` to component_2's template, you will see that it updates every time component_1 mutates its value.

component_2.component.ts

```
// Assuming that a task is a string
public tasksToUnassign: string[];

// Setup a local reference to the service property inside your constructor
constructor(private formService:FormService){
  this.tasksToUnassign = this.formService.selectedTasksToUnassign;
}
```

component_2.component.html

```
<ul>
  <!-- Use *ngFor to loop through each item of an array -->
  <li *ngFor="let task of tasksToUnassign">{{ task }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the service is using a regular value. If you want the values to update on every change. You need to use observables to hold the value.

And then in component_2.ts, you will subscribe to the value

#### Shared Service

```
  public selectedTasksToUnassignSubject = new Behaviour Subject<Array<Tasks>>([]);
```

This will keep the value of `selectedTasksToUnassignSubject` inside a behaviour Subject. Any component that wants to read it's value can subscribe to it. So whenever, the behaviour  subject updates, all the subscribers would get updated.

#### Updating Behaviour Subject Inside Component 1

```
service.selectedTasksToUnassignSubject.next(tasks);
```

#### Subscribing To The Value Of The Behaviour Subject

```
service.selectedTasksToUnassignSubject.subscribe(data=>{
//Code To Run Whenever the value of task changes
})
```

I can imagine `rxjs` getting quite confusing especially if you're just starting out with angular. But they are super useful and you will grow to love them once you understand how they work.

Comment: can you give me an example please?